# We are receiving KubepiLatencyHigh error in opsgenie

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi we are getting below error in opsgenie 
Error: The API server has a 99th percentile latency of 5.21555555555553 seconds for GET nodes.

So please help on to resolve this issue

Description:
1.[INT_Prometheus]: [FIRING:3] KubeAPILatencyHigh (https apiserver default monitoring/k8s 0.99 kubernetes 3)

Source
/#/alerts?receiver=opsgenie
Integration
INT_PROMETHEUS (Prometheus)
Responders
FCA_EMEA
Owner Team
FCA_EMEA
Alias
- alertname = KubeAPILatencyHigh - endpoint = https - job = apiserver - namespace = default - prometheus = monitoring/k8s - quantile = 0.99 - resource = nodes - scope = cluster - service = kubernetes - severity = 3 - verb = GET
Last Updated At
Apr 28, 2020 7:59 AM
Description
Alerts Firing:
Labels:
- alertname = KubeAPILatencyHigh
- endpoint = https
- job = apiserver
- namespace = default
- prometheus = monitoring/k8s
- quantile = 0.99
- resource = nodes
- scope = cluster
- service = kubernetes
- severity = 3
- verb = GET
Annotations:
- message = The API server has a 99th percentile latency of 5.21555555555553 seconds for GET nodes.
S
Labels:
- alertname = KubeAPILatencyHigh
- endpoint = https
- job = apiserver
- namespace = default
- prometheus = monitoring/k8s
- quantile = 0.99
- resource = pods
- scope = namespace
- service = kubernetes
- severity = 3
- verb = GET
Annotations:
- message = The API server has a 99th percentile latency of 8 seconds for GET pods.

Labels:
- alertname = KubeAPILatencyHigh
- endpoint = https
- job = apiserver
- namespace = default
- prometheus = monitoring/k8s
- quantile = 0.99
- resource = pods
- scope = namespace
- service = kubernetes
- severity = 3
- subresource = status
- verb = PUT
Annotations:
- message = The API server has a 99th percentile latency of 8 seconds for PUT pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes API server uses ETCD as a backing storage for all the kubernetes objects. I would start by looking at logs from ETCD server. Also setup alerts on `EtcdHighCommitDurations`, `EtcdHighFsyncDurations`, `EtcdHighNumberOfFailedGRPCRequests` to know if there is any issue going on with ETCD.